# Splitting text based on a delimiter in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have just started learning python. I am working on netflix_tiles dataset downloaded from Kaggle.  Some of the entries in the director column have multiple director names separated by column, i was trying to separate director names using the split function

The following is one of the original values loaded from the file to dataframe

> s7    Movie   My Little Pony: A New Generation,   **Robert Cullen, José Luis
> Ucha  Vanessa Hudgens**, ..

I am using the following code to do the split

```
def strip(x):
  x = x.strip().split(',')
  return x

director_counts = df["director"].apply(strip)
```

After the above code executes the output is as follows

> s7                     [Robert Cullen,  José Luis Ucha]

The director name is not split based on comma and I am also seeing the index(s7) is also returned from the function when i passed just the director column to the function. Can anyone please tell me why is it behaving in this way?
Edit:
Tried this as well

```
director_counts =  df['director'].str.split(',\s*')
```

Link to collab:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1OXJ9XKCBVg4-6W8Hiqfy4ZTkgz0IVqbR?usp=sharing

Comment: 1. Don't name your method the same as an existing one (the string.split() method) unless it does a very closely analogous function. 2. Don't call your method using the object.method() syntax unless you've defined it as a method (within the class defintion) and not as a top-level function (which is what your example shows).

Comment: maybe the formatting is wrong (`apply(strip)` alone out of the code block). Also you used `strip` without the `()` so you are not calling it

Comment: @ThePhoton, I have edited the code. There was a typo when the code is copied over.

Comment: It's still confusing (maybe to you as well as us; maybe even to Python) that you named your function the same as the existing string.strip() method.

Comment: As Obi Wan said, "That's not the comma you're looking for."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.strip()`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/damien/Downloads/netflix_titles.csv.zip')

directors = df['director'].str.split(',\s*')
```

Output:

```
>>> directors
0       [Kirsten Johnson]
1                     NaN
2       [Julien Leclercq]
3                     NaN
4                     NaN
              ...        
8802      [David Fincher]
8803                  NaN
8804    [Ruben Fleischer]
8805       [Peter Hewitt]
8806        [Mozez Singh]
Name: director, Length: 8807, dtype: object
```

**Update**

> I was expecting it to come in two different rows

Use `explode`:

```
>>> directors.explode()
0       Kirsten Johnson
1                   NaN
2       Julien Leclercq
3                   NaN
4                   NaN
             ...       
8802      David Fincher
8803                NaN
8804    Ruben Fleischer
8805       Peter Hewitt
8806        Mozez Singh
Name: director, Length: 9612, dtype: object  # <- 9612 rows instead of 8807
```

To get count per director, use `value_counts` (drop nan by default):

```
>>> directors.explode().value_counts()
Rajiv Chilaka     22
Jan Suter         21
Raúl Campos       19
Suhas Kadav       16
Marcus Raboy      16
                  ..
Raymie Muzquiz     1
Stu Livingston     1
Joe Menendez       1
Eric Bross         1
Mozez Singh        1
Name: director, Length: 4993, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Still not getting separated. I have added the link to collab.

Comment: What do you mean by *separated*? Directors of a same movie have been exploded into a list instead of a string, right?

Comment: I was expecting that that if the column has two director names seperated by comma. The result split the original string/content based on the comma delimiter.

Comment: It is exactly what my code does: `[Robert Cullen, José Luis Ucha]` then `[Pedro de Echave García, Pablo Azorín Williams]` and so on.

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: Maybe I got the basics wrong. I was expecting it to come in two different rows. Thanks

Comment: Ok, you are looking for to `explode`. I updated my answer, can you check it please?

Comment: @logeeks. You're welcome. Glad to read you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `df["director"].strip` in the line `director_counts = df["director"].strip`, you are actually accessing the `strip()` method of the pandas Series object, rather than applying the `strip()` method to each element of the Series. To apply the `strip()` method to each element, you should use the `apply()` method on the Series instead.

```
def strip(x):
    x = x.split(',')
    x = [obj.strip() for obj in x]
    return x

director_counts = df["director"].apply(strip)
```

Comment: I tried using this, it still is not seperating value based on comma s7  [Robert Cullen, José Luis Ucha]